# Search, input, button margin and padding

Tags: html, css, forms, css-transitions, margin

I would like to remove the space between `<input>` and `<button>`.

In the CSS, I tried with padding: `input, button {padding : 0px}`, but it didn't work.

```html
<form action="search">
  <div class="input-search">
    <span class="input-icon">
      <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
    </span>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Los Angeles" />
    <button type="submit">
      <strong>Search</strong>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you using any frameworks? CSS reset? etc?

Comment: Removing the space in the makup maybe? :`...Angeles" /><button...`

Comment: you mean like that? - https://ibb.co/s9QLFF6

Comment: Tkank you, Yes I want like that @sergeykuznetsov.

Comment: Thank you @LouysPatriceBessette it's ok, thank you so much it's simple but i'm junior , student. Thank

Answer (score 0):

`margin-left: -1em;` maybe?

Margin can have negative value...

```css
button{
  margin-left: -1em;
}
```

```html
<form action="search">
  <div class="input-search">
    <span class="input-icon">
      <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
    </span>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Los Angeles" /> <button type="submit"><strong>Search</strong></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `input-search` div style `display:flex`.

```html
<form action="search">
  <div class="input-search" style="display:flex;">
    <span class="input-icon">
      <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
    </span>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Los Angeles" /> <button type="submit"><strong>Search</strong></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried but the space does not leave I will try to add a second value of flexbox

Comment: It's ok, a member helped me, thank you for your help and for taking the time to respond.